# Android findViewById returning null after changing compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, null, findviewbyid

I've searched about the problem I'm having, but it is very specific and I couldn't find the answer for it.

I have the following code in my app:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        mStatusImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewStatus);
        ...
        mStatusImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               ...
            }
    ...
    }
```

I originally compiled and exported APK using:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

and everything works fine. But then I updated my app to the latest version:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Now here comes the strange part. With the latest version in compileSdk and buildTools, if I'm in debug mode, everything runs fine.

But if I export the APK file, after installing it in my device, when I run my app I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{x.x.x/x.x.x.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference : at x.x.x.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

This is a very strange problem... Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: clear project and build again

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` to set up the UI before programmatically interacting with any of its components. Your first 2 lines of `onCreate()` should be `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, then `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`. Then go ahead and set up the onTouchListener.

Comment: Yup, I'm doing that. I changed the question so that it is clear.

Comment: Maybe post your activity_main.xml contents as well so we can see the ImageView, etc.